# Finding the closest point on a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ to the origin given its parametric equations?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I have a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ and I've found its parametric and plane equations.
I thought of setting variables in the parametric equations to zero but, I keep getting different values for the parameters, so this is wrong.

Here is what I have:
$Plane Equations: x+3y+4z=8 $

Parametric Equations:

$x = t +3s$

$y = t - 5s $

$z = 2-t+3s$

How do I find the closest point on this plane to the origin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x+3y+4z=8$ is your plane. So then we know that $[1,3,8]$ is perpendicular to the plane.

We want this vector to go through the origin, so we can construe it as a parametrically given line:

(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)+t(1,3,4)=(t,3t,4t)

To make sure it is on the plane, substitute
$$x=t$$
$$y=3t$$
$$z=4t$$
back into the original equation for the plane:
$t+3(3t)+4(4t)=8$

$t=\frac{4}{13}$

Thus,  $(x,y,z)=\frac{4}{13}\cdot[1,3,4]=(4/13,12/13,16/13)$ is the closest point to the origin.

Comment: By this same method I was thinking, Can I use it to find the closest point on a line. How would I do this?

Comment: The closest distance between a point and a line? or the closest place on a line to a point

Comment: The idea is very similar. If you play around, you'll get an answer. Do it in general, let $(x,y,z)$ be an arbitrary point and $(a,b,c)+t[,j,k,l]$ be a line defined parametrically. Here's the first step: consider the locus of points perpendicular to the line. What other information do you need?

Comment: @TeyashArjun I just realized that I answered your other question about the relationship between lines an planes/ visualization. Does that help with this question as well?

Comment: Yes it really does thank you so much, for all the help, one last thing I'd like to know about planes is that number that all the x,y and z's are equal to, say d, does that d mean anything specifically? Like I know I can use it to find point of intersection, thats quite elementary at this point but like does it represent perhaps a distance from the origin or something.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that with this same plane I was asked to find two more planes that are parallel to this one. I thought of using the distance formula and adding and subtracting 2 from the distance but then I realized I don't know what to subtract it from in the plane equation.

Comment: So, I think of $d$ very much like the $b$ value in $y=mx+b$. This is because this form is a rearranged $ax+by=c$. Then $y=-ax+\frac{c}{b}$. In other words, it doesn't effect the slope. if you have $ax+by+cx=d$, the vector $[a,b,c]$ is perpendicular to this one, irrespective of $d$. Therefore, the $d$ is like a translation factor. All planes of the form $ax+by+cz=d$ are  parallel so long as $a,b,c$ are the same in the equation. So another plane that is parallel will be: $x+3y+4z=0$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34381/discussion-between-teyash-arjun-and-andres-mejia).

Answer (score 2):

Interpret the plane equation as
$$
\alpha \cdot u = \beta
$$
with $u = (x,y,z)^T$. If $\alpha \ne 0$, divide by its length:
$$
\frac{\alpha}{\lVert \alpha \rVert}  \cdot u = \frac{\beta}{\lVert \alpha \rVert}
$$
This is an equation of the form
$$
n \cdot u = d
$$
where $n$ is a unit normal vector of the plane and $d$ is the signed distance of the plane to the origin. So $\lvert d \rvert$ is the distance.

In your case we have $\alpha = (1,3,4)^T$ and $\beta = 8$.
Then $\lVert \alpha \rVert = \sqrt{1+9+16} = \sqrt{26}$.
We get $d = \beta / \lVert \alpha \rVert = 8/\sqrt{26} = \sqrt{64/26} = \sqrt{32/13} = 1.5689 \dotso$

The closest point is signed distance $d$ times the unit normal $n$.

Vectors from the origin to a point of the plane can be written as $q n + r n_\perp$ for some unit vector $n_\perp$ orthogonal to $n$, thus parallel to the plane, and would have a length $L=\sqrt{q^2 + p^2}$. This expression is minimal for vectors without a component parallel to the plane ($p = 0)$, being a multiple of $n$.
$$
d \, n = \frac{\beta}{\lVert \alpha \rVert^2} \alpha
$$
In your case
$$
\frac{8}{26} (1,3,4)^T = \frac{4}{13} (1,3,4)^T
$$

Here is a visualization:

[image: distance plane to origin]

([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKWp9.png))

Answer (score 0):

**Geometrical approach:** Foot of perpendicular drawn from the origin $(0, 0, 0)$ to the given plane: $x+3y+4z=8$ will be the closest point on the plane to the origin.

The foot of perpendicular drawn from any point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ to any plane: $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is given by [general formula](https://www.academia.edu/12372301/Reflection_of_a_point_about_a_line_and_a_plane_in_3-D_space_reflection_of_a_point_in_2-D_and_3-D_co-ordinate_systems_by_HCR_)
$$\left(\frac{x_0+x'}{2}, \frac{y_0+y'}{2}, \frac{z_0+z'}{2}\right)$$
where, (given $(x_0, y_0, z_0)\equiv (0, 0, 0)$) $$x'=x_0-\frac{2a(ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d)}{a^2+b^2+c^2}=0-\frac{2\cdot 1(0+3\cdot 0+4\cdot 0-8)}{1^2+3^2+4^2}=\frac {8}{13}$$
$$y'=y_0-\frac{2b(ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d)}{a^2+b^2+c^2}=0-\frac{2\cdot 3(0+3\cdot 0+4\cdot 0-8)}{1^2+3^2+4^2}=\frac {24}{13}$$
$$z'=z_0-\frac{2c(ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d)}{a^2+b^2+c^2}=0-\frac{2\cdot 4(0+3\cdot 0+4\cdot 0-8)}{1^2+3^2+4^2}=\frac {32}{13}$$
Now, setting the values of $x', y'$ & $z'$ the foot of perpendicular drawn from the origin $(x_0, y_0, z_0)\equiv(0, 0, 0)$ to the given plane is 
$$\left(\frac{0+\frac {8}{13}}{2}, \frac{0+\frac {24}{13}}{2}, \frac{0+\frac {32}{13}}{2}\right)\equiv \left(\frac{4}{13}, \frac{12}{13}, \frac{16}{13}\right)$$
Hence, $\color{red}{\left(\frac{4}{13}, \frac{12}{13}, \frac{16}{13}\right)}$ is the closest point on the given plane: $x+3y+4z=8$ to the origin.